# Should I consider resource expense of stack frame creation/ movement in method calls - are they significant?

Tags: performance, stack, frame

i am aware that the stack frame must be manipulated every time a method is called. This of course has a computational cost (a kind of overhead as far as i understand it). I was wondering what kind of significance this would have on general software development (as opposed to say the systems that guidance missiles - where efficiency would be a hightened consideration). Is this something a programmer should consider? Is this a consideration that only really applies where high levels of iteration/ recursion occur?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you programming?
Stuff where you have to count how many bytes (not KB, MB, but bytes) are used
because your memory is so small? (same for speed)
Then consider it. Else not.

The benefit from proper structured code (with function, classes...)
instead of spaghetti-code is *much* higher than the drawbacks of stack overhead.

Additionally, compiler optimization helps too.
It won´t nullify the stack usage, but it´s nothing to ignore either.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, pushing and popping stack frames costs CPU cycles. Does it matter? In tight inner loops, it may, and especially if you are using a language where the cost of function/method calls is high. In any case, if you are thinking about inlining a function/method, measure performance before and after to see if there is really a significant benefit.

Also, remember that depending on your language runtime/compiler may inline calls for you in some cases. If your compiler can do this, then writing functions in a way that the compiler is able to inline, is better than manually inlining the calls yourself.